# Filter using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, search, mysqli, filter

I am an programming amateur, working on a small project of mine but i got stucked when I wanted make filters for my mysql output.

All works when I fill all search input fields and submit, correct filtered result appears. But when I leave one field out nothing shows up (only else command) as using AND condition. If I use OR and leave it empty it shows all result without caring what has been filled in the required fields.

Would there be any way how to show result even if one of the field stays empty? I tried to play with a code from different post here in stackoverflow but no luck yet as i am not really much experienced and cannot figure out how to use this inside of my code.

```
if(isset($_POST["profilename"]) && $_POST["profilename"] != "") 
$sql .= " AND profilename = '". $_POST["profilename"] ."'";
```

Below here is my code, if you could have a look and suggest what i could edit so the filtering would be working.

```
<select class="form-control" id="Select1" name="departure">
<select class="form-control" id="Select2" name="destination">
<select class="form-control" id="Select3" name="layover">
```

...

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");

if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
$departure = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['departure']);
$destination = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['destination']);
$layover = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['layover']);



$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM crud 
WHERE departure LIKE '$departure%' 
AND kam LIKE '$kam' 
AND layover LIKE '$layover'
ORDER BY id DESC");



if($make = mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo '<div style="display:block;"'.$r['departure'].'</div>';
echo '<div style="display:block;"'.$r['kam'].'</div>';
echo '<div style="display:block;"'.$r['layover'].'</div>';
//following code..
}
}else{
echo'<h4>No match found!</h4>';

print ($make);
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($connection);
}

?>
```

For example: Filter `Departure` with `Destination` and leave `Layover` empty -> should return a result of desired `Departure and Destination` with ANY `Layover`.
or 2nd example: Fill `Destination` with `Layover` but leave `Departure` empty would result in  desired search of `Destination and Layover` with ANY `Departure`.

Please let me know if its possible with my code and possibly how.
Thank you so much guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check each input against an empty string in an OR condition within each of the different AND conditions.

```
"SELECT * FROM crud
WHERE ('$departure' = '' OR departure LIKE '$departure%')
AND ('$kam' = '' OR kam LIKE '$kam')
AND ('$layover' = '' OR layover LIKE '$layover')
ORDER BY id DESC"
```

This way, if one of the input parameters isn't given, the corresponding part of the condition will be interpreted as, for example, `('' = '' OR departure LIKE '$departure%')` which will evaluate as true for every row since `''` always equals `''` regardless of the LIKE comparison.

A couple of notes - first, without any wildcard characters, your LIKE comparisons basically work like `=`, (e.g. `kam LIKE '$kam'` will match the same rows as `kam = '$kam'`). So either just use = or add some wildcards in order for those to be useful.

Second, consider using prepared statements instead of concatenating values into your SQL like this. The concatenation approach makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection and various annoying errors (even if you escape the strings).

Comment: Perfect, this work well and the solution was quite easy! :) Would also have any specific advice what to change in my code so it is not vulnerable to sql injection? I am not really sure what I could change to prevent that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM crud 
WHERE (departure LIKE '$departure%' OR departure is null)
AND kam LIKE '$kam' 
AND (layover LIKE '$layover' OR departure is null)
ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's put the "dont build your queries using user input" aside.

If you want to go that path, you could use conditionals to build the query step by step.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM crud WHERE ";
if (!empty($departure)) {
  $query .= "departure LIKE '$departure%' AND ";
}
if (!empty($destination)) {
  $query .= "destination LIKE '$destination%' AND ";
}
if (!empty($layover)) {
  $query .= "layover LIKE '$layover' AND ";
}
$query .= "1 ORDER BY id DESC";
```

You will end up with some alternatives in the $query string:

```
NOTHING SELECTED:
SELECT * FROM crud WHERE 1 ORDER BY id DESC

SOMETHING SELECTED:
SELECT * FROM crud WHERE departure LIKE '$departure%' AND layover LIKE '$layover' AND 1 ORDER BY id DESC

ALL SELECTED:
SELECT * FROM crud WHERE departure LIKE '$departure%' AND destination LIKE '$destination%' AND layover LIKE '$layover' AND 1 ORDER BY id DESC
```

This should cover it.
Have a good day